MySQL query returning unexpected result for counting query
I have a MySQL table named members with the following structure and sample data:



id
memberOneId
memberTwoId
memberOneScore
memberTwoScore




1
1002
1001
100
90


2
1002
1001
95
65


3
1001
1002
55
60



My exmple user has ID 1001. I want to get count of his victories with scores he have with follwing query:
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `members` 
where (`memberOneId` = 1001 and `memberOneScore` > `memberTwoScore`)         
   or (`memberTwoId` = 1001 and `memberTwoScore` > `memberOneScore`)

I expect this query to return 0, as the user with ID 1001 always has a lower score than their opponent in all rows.
However, the query is returning 1 as the result.
Can anyone help me understand why this query is returning an unexpected result and suggest how to fix it?
I always get unexpected result.

replace select count(*) as aggregate with select *, and the you should see the record that gets selected.

I would ask to list the table structure.  If the data types are character and you are expecting numeric computation,  "100" is less than "90" as 1 is before 9.  Get proper data type and that MIGHT be your issue?

Or convert to numbers in the query: WHERE memberOneScore+0 > memberTwoScore+0

But using correct datatypes is usually best.

I don't know what is your scores column datatype. If it's integer then your query will work properly.
Otherwise do type cast and updated query is:
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `members` 
where (`memberOneId` = 1001 and cast(`memberOneScore` as signed int) > cast(`memberTwoScore` as signed int)) 
or    (`memberTwoId` = 1001 and cast(`memberTwoScore` as signed int) > cast(`memberOneScore` as signed int))

Sample code: db<>fiddle
Thank you

Thank you very much! It really was a data type issue.
I did not notice how previous developer of project I am working on created that columns as VARCHAR instead of INT.
Thank you all)
